# How does one type pitch accent indicators?

Tags: html, cjk

In a lot of posts in here I've seen people using the method I prefer to represent pitch, with red lines that follow the binary contour, such as:

やかん{HLL}

Is there a way to do that without typing HLL or what have you in brackets? Also, does anyone know what you call red lines like that? I'd like to know how to make those lines in HTML or really anywhere outside of stack exchange.

Comment: It is done by using a custom javascript you can find here https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js You can add it to your website to use it's features like the one you gave, but the formatting is only visual, done by the browser, and thus cannot be brought over to any other platform or website

Comment: @Randommm, would you consider posting that as a proper answer, instead of as a comment?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I just looked for how it was done, but I don't have want to look at how to implement it properly for yourself so it wouldn't be a complete answer. if you or someone else wants to do that, go ahead

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment by Randommm, the [Japanese Language Stackexchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) uses the "JLSE Hacks" library in combination with jQuery 1.12.4, but it's a plugin specifically written for use on Stackexchange sites, and so it *only* works for HTML elements that use the same classes as are used on Stackexchange sites.

For instance, this works fine:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js?v=504677583821"></script>

<p class="js-post-body">やかん{HLL}</p>
```

But this will do nothing:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js?v=504677583821"></script>

<p>やかん{HLL}</p>
```

If we examine the source over on https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/japanese-l-u.js we see that the following query selector is used to match elements that should be processed, found in the `loop` function:

```
.js-post-body, .question-hyperlink, .module sidebar-related,
.excerpt, .answer-hyperlink, .summary, .question-summary,
.answer-summary, .question-title, .answer-title, .top-detail,
.js-wmd-preview, #question-header, .comment-text, .comment-body,
.single-badge-summary, .lines, .async-load, .history-table
```

So to answer "Is there a way to do that without typing HLL or what have you in brackets": no, not if you're using this library. It needs that markup. However, you can certainly write something that sits *between* jQuery and this library with a dictionary that knows which words use which pitch levels, and have that auto-inject the `{HLL}` codes first. Of course, that'd be a huge library, and it would only work for words that are unambiguous (i.e. it would only work reliably for words with kanji, or words with unique pronunciation - something that basically doesn't exist for Japanese).

> I'd like to know how to make those lines in HTML or really anywhere outside of stack exchange.

So inspect the DOM on the Japanese Language Stackexchange site: posts with Japanese that use pitch information simply tag each element with a class, and CSS takes care of the rest. If you want to do this on your own site, without the added `{HLL}` kind of code, you could just add similar CSS classes to each kana yourself:

```css
.ja-text.tone-h {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.ja-text.tone-l {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.tone-l-change {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.tone-h-change {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p class="ja-text" lang="ja">
  <span class="tone-h ja-text" lang="ja">や</span><span class="tone-l-change ja-text" lang="ja">か</span><span class="tone-l ja-text" lang="ja">ん</span>
</p>
```

But then you'd be better off using CSS properly, because you don't need a separate class for "low to high" or "high to low", CSS already lets you directly specify those transitions using `+` in the CSS query selector:

```css
[lang="ja"] {
  width: 20em;
}

[lang="ja"] .pitch span {
  margin: 0 -0.2em;
  padding: 0 0.1em;
}

.pitch .h {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.pitch .l {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.pitch .l + .h,
.pitch .h + .l {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p lang="ja">
  色は匂へど散り<span class="pitch">
    <span class="l">ぬ</span>
    <span class="l">る</span>
    <span class="h">を</span>
  </span>我が世誰ぞ常ならん有為の奥山今日越えて浅き夢見じ酔ひもせず
</p>
```